# Java: Creating a new instance of the UI class

Tags: java

I have two classes: class A and class B. class A has a main method. Class B is the User Interface (JFrame). I want to have an instance of B in A, but when I write any of the following the program runs but no window shows:

```
public class A{
    static B d= new B();
        public static void main(String args[]){
                           d.setVisible(true);} }



public class A{
        public static void main(String args[]){
         java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new B().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        }}


public class A{
            public static void main(String args[]){
             B d= new B()
             d.setVisible(true); 
            }}
```

How can I show the window?

Comment: What is "JForm"? Usually you would want to call `setVisible`, and probably `pack`, on a `JFrame`.

Comment: sorry I meant JFrame. I'll edit it. I tried using d.pack() but the window is still now showing.

Comment: Did you set the size of the JFrame?

Comment: I did set the size. I added breakpoints starting at the new B() instruction, and when I debug the code it looks like it's only executing the instructions before the new B(). When it gets to that instruction, the cursor just disappears and no matter how many break points I have after that it never reaches them.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you didn't show us the code for class B. Perhaps the following example can give you a hint:

```
public class B extends JFrame {
    public B() {
        super("Hello, JFrame!");
    }
}

public class A {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.setSize(300, 400);
        b.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It's a very minimal example, but as you can see `B` inherits from JFrame. In `A`'s main method, you first create a new instance of `B`, then set its size and make it visible.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was in class A. I had an instruction that was waiting for input from a stream before the new B() but it wasn't getting the input.

Comment: Don't forget to close this question.